# Is there a way to add multi-paged shinysurvey output to a modal dialog?

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

I have an rshiny app and I'd like to add a multi-paged survey using shinysurveys, but I'd only like that survey to appear when a "Take survey" button is clicked. I'm also hoping for it to be contained in a modal dialog.

I almost have this working, but the "pages" all get condensed into one.  Any suggestions?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinysurveys)

survey <- data.frame(
  question = c("Question 1", "Question 2"),
  option = c("Answer 1", "Answer 2"),
  input_type = c("text", "text"),
  input_id = c("answer_1", "answer_2"),
  dependence = c(NA,NA),
  dependence_value = c(NA,NA),
  required =c(F, F), 
  page = c(1,2)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(actionButton("clickforsurvey", "Take Survey")),
  br()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  
  observeEvent(input$clickforsurvey, { 
    showModal(modalDialog(
      shinysurveys::surveyOutput(
        survey, survey_title = "Analyst Survey"
      )))
    
    renderSurvey(survey)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `surveyOutput` stops working inside a `modalDialog`, but if you wrap it with, for example, `basicPage` it works.

```
showModal(modalDialog(
      shiny::basicPage(
        shinysurveys::surveyOutput(
          survey,
          survey_title = "Analyst Survey"
        )
      )
    ))
```

**App**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinysurveys)

survey <- data.frame(
  question = c("Question 1", "Question 2"),
  option = c("Answer 1", "Answer 2"),
  input_type = c("text", "text"),
  input_id = c("answer_1", "answer_2"),
  dependence = c(NA, NA),
  dependence_value = c(NA, NA),
  required = c(F, F),
  page = c(1, 2)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(actionButton("clickforsurvey", "Take Survey")),
  br()
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$clickforsurvey, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      shiny::basicPage(
        shinysurveys::surveyOutput(
          survey,
          survey_title = "Analyst Survey"
        )
      )
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using Javascript to override some of the modal settings that seemed to be overriding the shinysurvey settings. I think your option is easier though.